# Service worker is throwing me an unexpected error as soon as i go offline

Tags: javascript, service-worker, workbox

Im using workbox module to handle my service worker file. The code below:

```
importScripts('https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/6.4.1/workbox-sw.js');

const { routing, strategies, cacheableResponse, expiration, recipes } = workbox;
const { registerRoute } = routing;
const {offlineFallback} = recipes;
const {ExpirationPlugin} = expiration;
const { StaleWhileRevalidate } = strategies;
const { CacheableResponsePlugin } = cacheableResponse;


self.__WB_MANIFEST;
registerRoute(
  ({ request }) => request.destination === 'script', // Only match requests with the destination set as 'script'
  new StaleWhileRevalidate({
    cacheName: 'js-cache', // Name for the cache
    plugins: [
      new CacheableResponsePlugin({ statuses: [0, 200] }), // Cache only responses with status 0 or 200
      new ExpirationPlugin({
         // Only cache requests for a week
         maxAgeSeconds: 7 * 24 * 60 * 60,
     
      })
    ],
  })
);
workbox.routing.setCatchHandler(({ event }) => {
    if (event.request.destination === 'document') {
      return caches.match('/offline.html');
    }
    return Response.error();
  });
```

I wanted it to work offline and serve cached files. But as soon as I try offline mode it crashes and shows me this error

```
Cannot read properties of null (reading '__jstcache')
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWJWf.png)

---

Answer (score 0):

Hope this code snippet work will work for you. Basically you should use async await and serve your wrap your code in try catch block and serve your offline file in catch block.

```
const offlinePage = '/offline/';
/**
 * Pages to cache
 */
workbox.routing.registerRoute(/\/posts.|\/articles/,
  async ({event}) => {
    try {
      return await workbox.strategies.staleWhileRevalidate({
          cacheName: 'cache-pages'
      }).handle({event});
    } catch (error) {
      return caches.match(offlinePage);
    }
  }
);

Please change accordingly in the code.
```

Comment: It still throws the same error. And I noticed when i go offline it clears the cache.